# extruding handle of mug

Tags: mesh, extrude

I am making the coffee mug of "blender guru" in donut tutorial,
when I extrude a face for handle and extrude again for second time,when I want to rotate it.the rotation influences whole the mug n faces.please tell me what should I do.

[image: as you see I don't have control on eatch extuded part.they are smoothy connected together n rotation n scale n movement influences intire the mug.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have "proportion editing on", this means you'll edit all the vertex inside the "area" controlled by the "proportional size".

disable it clicking on this icon:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer